# Combining data frame variables from split()

Tags: r, dplyr, split, tidyr

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
      Date monthyear Year JulianDate Period Plot.No Site Catch Cut Mgmt Treat Block Tcham Tsoil methaneflux WTD 
1 26/07/2012  Jul-2012 2012        208    Pre       1    M     C   R   FI     C    B1 17.27 16.13         0.0 -10 
2 26/07/2012  Jul-2012 2012        208    Pre       2    M     C   R   FI     C    B2 17.29 14.05        10.1  -5 
3 26/07/2012  Jul-2012 2012        208    Pre       3    M     C   R   FI     C    B3 17.31 13.82        19.5 -13 
4 26/07/2012  Jul-2012 2012        208    Pre       4    M     C   R   FI     C    B4 18.51 14.39         0.0 -16 
5 26/07/2012  Jul-2012 2012        208    Pre      25    M     T   R   BR    T5    B1 18.38 15.50         0.0 -11
6 26/07/2012  Jul-2012 2012        208    Pre      26    M     T   R   LB    T4    B1 18.19 17.12         0.0 -12
```

I'd like to split this into a dataframe that has a column of methaneflux for each monthyear factor combination e.g

```
plotno site jul2012 aug2012 sep2012 
1      M    5       5       8
2      W    9       9       5
3      M    4       6       6
4      M    3       3       3
```

I've used

```
split(ghg2, ghg2$monthyear)
```

This gives me a list of data frames where each month is it's own dataframe
What I'm struggling with is combining these dataframe to get the df I want, given the plot.no have to match

Is split() the right Tidyr bit for this or should I have used something else?

Comment: I prefer grouping dataframes over splitting them. Also leaving them together and then plotting them with faceting.

Answer (score 0):

Try tidyverse approach to do this

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
    select(Plot.No, Site, monthyear, methaneflux) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = 'monthyear', values_from = 'methaneflux')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produced the error:
Error in select(., Plot.No, Site, monthyear, methaneflux) : 
  unused arguments (Plot.No, Site, monthyear, methaneflux)

I then tried the pivot wider function without the select but got this:
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates |

I simplified the data to only contain 
monthyear siteplot methaneflux WTD

Comment: I don't think pivot_wider is working because I have replicated values, e.g each time point has an M1 (they are plots over time), is there any way to work around this?

Comment: I will try if you can edit the question and provide a sample data frame